# Can a .iml file pull data into project without a corresponding gradle dependency?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I inherited someone's Android project and am trying to remove any unused code to streamline it.

In the process, I found a module with a `.iml` file but in the `build.gradle` file there is no corresponding gradle import/implementation naming that module. Would this `.iml` file actually import a module into my project?

Also, if no code is added because of the `.iml`, is it safe to say that I can count it as unused code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. An .iml file is the IntelliJ IDEA project file.

if you did not find any build.gradle - then it may not be a gradle based project!
How are you determining that it is gradle based ? are there any other gradle related files ?

if there are no other gradle files - it may have been project setup directly via IntelliJ with out any build tool.
you can attempt to open the whole project in IntelliJ and see if works

Comment: Thank you -- I edited my question for clarity: a `build.gradle` file exists for the whole project, but it doesn't appear for that particular folder/module in question; the only thing contained in the mystery module is the `.iml` file. Without a dependency listed in the `app`'s `build.gradle`, is it safe to say that the `.iml` is not pulling any code into the project without me realizing?